# MYSQL Remove string between two known strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a WordPress website and following a change of theme I have to modify the structure of a thousand links present on about fifty pages. I would like to do it in SQL via PHPMYADMIN.

Is there a way in SQL to remove the end of all my link with the following structure :

```
- <a href="https://website.com/cours/les-problemes/lecon/s1-2014-2015-mathematiques-les-problemes/">
- <a href="https://website.com/cours/la-division/lecon/s3-2014-2015-mathematiques-la-division-n-nakatani/">
- <a href="https://website.com/cours/mathematiques-larithmetique/lecon/201819-s5-fa-mathematiques-nathalie-nakatani/">
```

In order to only get :

```
- <a href="https://website.com/cours/les-problemes/">
- <a href="https://website.com/cours/la-division/">
- <a href="https://website.com/cours/mathematiques-larithmetique/">
```

I tried to use the answer of this topic : [MYSQL Replace string between two known strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726256/mysql-replace-string-between-two-known-strings) but I did not manage to find a solution to fit my purpose.

I also thought about doing it in two parts :
1- Remove the content between the '**/lecon/**' and the '**">**'.
2- Then remove completely all the iteration of '/lecon/' of my pages, because they only occur on the links that I want to edit.
But my knowledges in SQL are limited and I have no clue of how to do the first part.

My apologizes for my English.

Thanks in avance for any helps !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can try using a regex replacement:

```sql
SELECT
    tag,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(tag, '(<a href="https?://(?:[^/]+/){3}).*">', '$1">')
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks I will try it in few days. I just need the client "go".

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL < 8 (5.7), without `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/lecon/', -1) FROM url), '">'), 'lecon/', '') FROM `your_table`
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/dxFpNywb)

Using your idea, I removed all from `/lecon/` to the end in STEP 1 and concatenated `">` to repair the HTML URL, and then I replaced `lecon/` with an empty string in STEP 2.

Comment: Thanks for this alternative ! I will also give it a try in few days !